# Multiple images in Android app

Tags: android, performance, android-image

Let's say I have 100 PNG files (images) I want to use in my Android app. If I add them all in the drawable folder, would that be a performance impediment? If yes, what alternatives do I have?

I mention that I won't use them all at the same time. Most probably, I will need 6 of them at any given time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only storing them in a folder would not be a performance impediment.
As long as you do not load the images in your code, performances are not involved. 
Then it's up to your use to choose to load them all at the start of your app, or on demand when your app is running.

Answer (score 1):

It shouldn't impede the performance of your app in any way, however you may want to consider clever ways of compressing the images to reduce APK size or the times to load individual images i.e vector drawables or webp.

See https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=r_LpCi6DQME